# django 1.8 cannot load css in development server

Tags: django

I have problem to load css for admin site. I just setup django 1.8 and run development server but apparently it cannot load css with 500 error code. I cannot figure out what is the problem.

This is my setting.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = secret_key

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rnd.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rnd.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'rnd.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

this is the error that i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 64, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 189, i
n __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 54, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 47, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\views.py", line
 40, in serve
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\static.py", line 66, in serve

    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fullpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 290, in guess_type
    init()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 351, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 254, in read_windows_registry
    with _winreg.OpenKey(hkcr, subkeyname) as subkey:
TypeError: must be string without null bytes or None, not str
[08/Jul/2015 11:04:29]"GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

This is url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

The solution:

The root cause for this is because of the corrupted keys in the Windows Registry. I have reinstalled the python 2.7 library and it solved the problem.

Comment: What is the (full) error; please [edit] your question with the relevant traceback section of the error message.

Comment: Also, how is your main `urls.py` set-up?

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure how important that secret key is, but you just posted it to the internet. Might be worth switching to a new one now....

Comment: evrything is a standard code as we use the startproject command

Comment: Could [this](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/) be helpful? The author complains about corrupted keys in Windows Registry. It also provides links to issues in Python's bugtracker: [22028](https://bugs.python.org/issue22028) and [23604](https://bugs.python.org/issue23604)

Comment: @soon, it helps. I updated to the latest python 2.7 and problem solved. Not sure why windows registry become corrupted

Comment: Could you, please, post an answer, so other users, facing the same problem would solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause for this is because of the corrupted keys(have empty string/null value) in the Windows Registry. I have reinstalled the python 2.7 library and it solved the problem.

Comment: Some useful background information and possible solutions are available [here](http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/04/23/python-pip-and-windows-registry-corruption/)